# adding prefix to figure caption in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, tex, typesetting, mathematical-typesetting

How can I change the caption of all figures in LaTeX to include a prefix?  For example, make all figures appear as "Supplementary Figure 1", "Supplementary Figure 2", ... rather than "Figure 1", "Figure 2"?

thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer is to use the following command:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}
```

Answer (score 23):

To number labels with prefix 'S', use:
`\renewcommand{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}`
`\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}`
`\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}`
`\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}`

To modify the text used at the start of a caption: 
`\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplemental Material, Figure}`

Source: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Customizing_numbering_pages.html

Comment: Is there a way to only do this for the Supplementary Section, but not the other main sections?

Comment: @ajl123 Just put these commands after the main sections, but before the supplementary sections

Answer (score 5):

Add the second line as well if you would like restart numbering of figures to start at 1.

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```